# How to make a Cardview expand by clicking it?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to make some Cardview expand when clicking. I was able to do this by setting the original Cardview size to 50dp and then setting its height to WRAP_CONTENT, as shown in the image below:

[image]

**Here's the code:**

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        holder.cvCard.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(holder.cvCard.getWidth(), ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
});
```

The problem, as you can see, is that by changing the size of the Cardview, it loses its margins and looks that way misaligned. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 4):

Do this

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if(YOURCARDVIEW.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
     YOURCARDVIEW.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
     YOURCARDVIEW.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
   });
```

And in your XML keep the `visibility= gone`

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

Your view holder xml code should look similar to this:

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            android:clipChildren="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!--visible content-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lytVisible"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_print_black_24dp"
                        android:tint="#555555"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Click me to expand"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textColor="#333333"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <!--end visible content-->

                <!--hidden content-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lytHidden"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."/>

                </LinearLayout>
                <!--end hidden content-->

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And here your java code:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View hiddenView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.lytHidden);
            hiddenView.setVisibility( hiddenView.getVisibility() == View.GONE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Good luck!